How do React Native uncontrolled components manage their state?
Do these components use refs as state? When we update the component ref, do we update the DOM directly? When we update the component's ref, does the component render and show the value or the change on the screen? If I create an internal state (useState) in the component, but do not update that state, is the component still controlled?
This is an example of an uncontrolled TextInput. In this example I am using a core component (which has its native implementation and is not controlled by default). So I use a Ref to access the text that is inserted into the Input:
//TextInput Uncontrolled
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet,  TextInput, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 50,
    margin: 12,
    marginTop: 300,
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default function TextInputUncontrolled () {
  const textInputRef = React.useRef(null);
  let value = "";
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    value = textInputRef.current?.value;
    console.log (value);
    Alert.alert('Value:', value);
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        ref = {textInputRef}
        style = {styles.input}
        onChangeText = {(e) => (textInputRef.current.value = e)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Submit"
        onPress={handleSubmit}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

I don't know, for example, how TextInput manages its state internally. And how it updates the screen with the text that is entered without using useState and passes this value with Ref. If I want, for example, to create a component with a similar behavior, I don't know how I would do it. And if I, for example, create a custom component encapsulating the TextInput and create a useState that will only update when I want to use the controlled version of the component and when I want to use the uncontrolled version, I would not pass this state as a parameter.

What’s an example of a React Native uncontrolled component?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Okay, I'll give you an example. @johnhaup

RN uses native platform's own state management mechanisms for uncontrolled components. This is how it works
Bridge Communication:
React Native uses JavaScript bridge to communicate with native UI components
Uncontrolled components maintains its own state so JS side keeps a reference to this component, but doesn't directly control its entire state
Platform Specific State:
On iOS (UIKit):
Uses native responder chain and view state management
On Android (Android View system):
Uses View state and property tracking
In short, the answer to your question is no. React Native doesn’t use useReffor uncontrolled elements, and its state management is more complex than we think. It uses React tags, and each component gets a uniquereactTag that acts as an internal identifier across the JS and native layers.
This behavior might have changed, and you can read more about it here:
New Suspense SSR Architecture in React 18 and Document Controlled vs Uncontrolled Component Design pattern
As far as I know, I haven’t found anything interesting yet that, as a consumer, we don't need to worry about. Just knowing how to use it is enough. However, if you really want to deep dive, you can explore its source code. Unfortunately, there aren’t enough details about this topic in the articles or videos I’ve come across.
Updated
useControlledState
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export function useControlledState<T, C = T>(
  value: Exclude<T, undefined>,
  defaultValue: Exclude<T, undefined> | undefined,
  onChange?: (v: C, ...args: any[]) => void
): [T, (value: T, ...args: any[]) => void];
export function useControlledState<T, C = T>(
  value: Exclude<T, undefined> | undefined,
  defaultValue: Exclude<T, undefined>,
  onChange?: (v: C, ...args: any[]) => void
): [T, (value: T, ...args: any[]) => void];
export function useControlledState<T, C = T>(
  value: T,
  defaultValue: T,
  onChange?: (v: C, ...args: any[]) => void
): [T, (value: T, ...args: any[]) => void] {
  let [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(value || defaultValue);

  let isControlledRef = useRef(value !== undefined);
  let isControlled = value !== undefined;
  useEffect(() => {
    let wasControlled = isControlledRef.current;
    if (wasControlled !== isControlled) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.warn(
        `WARN: A component changed from ${wasControlled ? 'controlled' : 'uncontrolled'} to ${isControlled ? 'controlled' : 'uncontrolled'}.`
      );
    }
    isControlledRef.current = isControlled;
  }, [isControlled]);

  let currentValue = isControlled ? value : stateValue;
  let setValue = useCallback(
    (value: any, ...args: any[]) => {
      let onChangeCaller = (value: any, ...onChangeArgs: any[]) => {
        if (onChange) {
          if (!Object.is(currentValue, value)) {
            onChange(value, ...onChangeArgs);
          }
        }
        if (!isControlled) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
          currentValue = value;
        }
      };

      if (typeof value === 'function') {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.warn(
          'We can not support a function callback. See Github Issues for details https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum/issues/2320'
        );
        let updateFunction = (oldValue: any, ...functionArgs: any[]) => {
          let interceptedValue = value(
            isControlled ? currentValue : oldValue,
            ...functionArgs
          );
          onChangeCaller(interceptedValue, ...args);
          if (!isControlled) {
            return interceptedValue;
          }
          return oldValue;
        };
        setStateValue(updateFunction);
      } else {
        if (!isControlled) {
          setStateValue(value);
        }
        onChangeCaller(value, ...args);
      }
    },
    [isControlled, currentValue, onChange]
  );

  return [currentValue, setValue];
}


useHeader
import { useRouter, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

import { LINKS } from '@/config';
import { Roles } from '@/enums';
import useSwitchProfile from '@/hooks/remote/useSwitchProfile';
import useMe from '@/hooks/useMe';
import { TextColorProps } from '@/types';

import { useControlledState } from './useControlledState';

export type HeaderVersions = 'full' | 'basic' | 'none';
export type HeaderThemes = 'light' | 'dark' | 'yellow' | 'transparent-white';

export default function useHeader({
  version,
  theme,
  isMenuOpenProp,
  onMenuOpenChangeProp,
}: {
  version: HeaderVersions;
  theme: HeaderThemes;
  isMenuOpenProp?: boolean;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  onMenuOpenChangeProp?: (isOpen: boolean) => void;
}) {
  const userData = useMe();
  const { isSwitching, switchProfile } = useSwitchProfile();

  const router = useRouter();
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useControlledState(
    isMenuOpenProp,
    false, // default value if not controlled
    onMenuOpenChangeProp
  );
  const isHidden = version === 'none';
  const isLight = theme === 'light';
  const isYellow = theme === 'yellow';
  const isBlack = theme === 'dark';
  const isTransparentWhite = theme === 'transparent-white';
  const textColorBasedOnTheme =
    isLight || isYellow ? 'charcoal' : ('white' as TextColorProps);
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const dashboardUrl =
    userData?.role === Roles.ADMIN
      ? LINKS.DASHBOARD_OVERVIEW
      : userData?.role === Roles.LANDLORD ||
          userData?.role === Roles.SUB_USER ||
          userData?.role === Roles.AGENT
        ? LINKS.DASHBOARD_PROPERTIES_STATS
        : userData?.role === Roles.TENANT
          ? LINKS.TENANT_DASHBOARD_APPLICATIONS
          : LINKS.LOGIN;

  const handleDashboardClick = () => {
    router.push(dashboardUrl);
  };
  const handleSettingClick = () => {
    router.push(LINKS.PROFILE);
  };
  const isUserOnProfilePage = pathname === LINKS.PROFILE;

  const shouldHideSwitchProfileButton =
    (userData?.role !== Roles.LANDLORD && userData?.role !== Roles.TENANT) ||
    !isUserOnProfilePage;

  const switchRoleMessage =
    userData?.role === Roles.LANDLORD
      ? 'Switch to Tenant'
      : 'Switch to Landlord';
  return {
    onDashboardClick: handleDashboardClick,
    dashboardUrl,
    isBlack,
    isYellow,
    isLight,
    isTransparentWhite,
    textColorBasedOnTheme,
    isHidden,
    isMenuOpen,
    setIsMenuOpen,
    onSettingClick: handleSettingClick,
    shouldHideSwitchProfileButton,
    switchRoleMessage,
    onSwitchProfile: () => {
      switchProfile();
    },
    isProfileSwitching: isSwitching,
  };
}

I have added a code example from a real-world project. You can use the same approach to create any kind of custom component. Now, I can use the useHeader as controlled or uncontrolled

Thanks for your answer, the purpose of my question is to know how these components do this so that I can replicate it in components I create. I updated the question with example code. So the key point is: if I want to make a component that can be controlled or uncontrolled depending on the properties I pass as parameters, how do I do that?

So, you want to create a reusable custom component and allow the consumer to utilize it either as controlled or uncontrolled?

I have added a code example you can follow. This approach is being used by many big open-source projects, such as Adobe, NextUI, etc

That's not exactly what I wanted to know. The component is not supposed to change from controlled to uncontrolled during execution. It is supposed to be hybrid so that if I want it controlled in my application, it will always be controlled throughout the execution. And if I want to use it uncontrolled, it will always be uncontrolled throughout the execution. And I don't have to pass a value or defaultValue to use the uncontrolled version. Just passing an onChange to get the value as in the example I gave.

And if I want to use the controlled version, then I create a useState and pass a value as a property. I don't know if I understood this code well, but that's what I understood. You create a Ref and a useState takes value or defaultValue and compares the two, if I pass value I am using it controlled and if I pass defaultValue value I am using it uncontrolled. This answers part of my question, which is can I create a useState and if I don't use it, the component remains uncontrolled. Is that right?

Yes, you are right, and this code also solves the same problem, though with a different approach. However, you can use ref for internal state management; it is always up to you. I think you misunderstood the code I shared, especially the warning part, which is only for awareness. You mentioned that if a component is uncontrolled, it will stay uncontrolled throughout its execution, and vice versa, and that code is doing exactly the same.
